# Dynamic Expressions and Dynamic String Manipulation

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

So, I am trying to learn how to put together my own expressions, pass objects and compile to retrieve generated result, and I am stuck trying to understand exactly where my object instance goes in all of this.

So this is what I have gotten so far from reading through the code and stepping through

1. Create your object instance, your expressionstring, and parameters.

   ```
   T SampleString = "Some String I have";
   var operation= "it.Replace(@0, @1)";
   var operationParameters = new [] { "e", "CLOWN"};
   ```
2. Create a ParameterExpression object to specify the type of parameter your operation will be performed on

   ```
   ParameterExpression[] parameters = new ParameterExpression[] { Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "") };
   ```
3. Using the ExpressionParser class, create the expression you need to be executed against your object there

   ```
   ExpressionParser parser = new ExpressionParser(parameters, operation, operationParameters );
   ```
4. Called the ExpressionParser Parse method to retrieve the generated Expression, passing it the type of the result you want

   ```
   var generatedExpression = parser.Parse(typeof(String));
   ```
5. Now call the Expression.Lamba, passing it the generatedExpression, and the item

   ```
   var StringReplaceresult = Expression.Lambda<Func<T,String> >(generatedExpression , parameters).Compile()(item);
   ```

I am not quite sure if the above is correct, or where exactly the issue I am having with it starts. I do know that my Compile fails (5). The message is about not passing in the right number of parameters to the Expression.Lamba method there. But I wonder if that is really where the problem is as, again, I am not sure I get this even 60%, so I would appreciate it is someone would please correct my work above, where necessary.

Comment: What is `ExpressionParser`? Is it coming from some library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using the Dynamic Linq Query Library described by Scott Guthrie:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

If so, I think you want:

```
string sampleString = "some string I have";
var operation= "it.Replace(@0, @1)";
var operationParameters = new [] { "e", "CLOWN"};
Expression<Func<string, string>> expr = DynamicExpression.ParseLambda<string, string>(operation, operationParameters);
string result = expr.Compile().Invoke(sampleString);
```

When I run this in LinqPad the value of `result` is "somCLOWN string I havCLOWN"

The `DynamicExpression.ParseLambda` allows you to specify the parameter types as generic type arguments, rather than doing it by explicit creation of a `ParameterExpression` array as you were doing.

The `ParseLambda<>` call returns a strongly typed `Expression<TDelegate>` object and it's `Compile()` method compiles the underlying lambda expression into executable code and returns it as a delegate of the correct type that can then be invoked. That means the `Invoke()` returns an object of the correct type(`string` in this case) rather than an `object` that has to be cast. So even though you start off with non-strongly-typed code, you get back to type-safety as quickly as possible.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345362.aspx

p.s.

And in the source code I have, `ExpressionParser` is internal, you naughty boy/girl ;o)

Comment: Thanks. That did the trick. What does the Compile() function actually do?

Comment: Updated my answer with some extra explanation of the approach